# Rails 5 accepts_nested_attributes_for Getting Unprocessable Entity with JSON POST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, accepts-nested-attributes

I think I have all of this setup right for being able to send nested attributes, however, I keep getting 422 unprocessable entity but no error message. Here is how I have things configured:

**scouting_report.rb**

```
class ScoutingReport < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :scouting_report_details
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :scouting_report_details, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

**scouting_report_detail.rb**

```
class ScoutingReportDetail < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :scouting_report
end
```

**scouting_reports_controller.rb**

```
def scouting_report_params
  params.require(:scouting_report).permit(
    :customer_id, 
    :report_date, 
    :crop_id, 
    :wind_speed, 
    :wind_speed_direction, 
    :wind_speed_degree, 
    :temperature, 
    :sky, 
    :crop_growth_stage, 
    :crop_condition_comments, 
    :stand_count, 
    :irrigation_comment, 
    :crop_water_use, 
    :crop_water_use_units, 
      scouting_report_details_attributes: [
        :id, 
        :action, 
        :disorder_id, 
        :disorder, 
        :identifiaction, 
        :lon, 
        :level, 
        :lat, 
        :scouting_report_id])
end
```

Here is how the data looks in the schema:

```
  create_table "scouting_reports", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "customer_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",              null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",              null: false
    t.datetime "report_date"
    t.integer  "crop_id"
    t.string   "wind_speed"
    t.string   "wind_speed_direction"
    t.string   "wind_speed_degree"
    t.string   "temperature"
    t.string   "sky"
    t.string   "crop_growth_stage"
    t.text     "crop_condition_comments"
    t.string   "stand_count"
    t.text     "irrigation_comment"
    t.string   "crop_water_use"
    t.string   "crop_water_use_units"
  end

  create_table "scouting_report_details", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "disorder"
    t.integer  "disorder_id"
    t.string   "level"
    t.string   "action"
    t.string   "identifiaction"
    t.string   "lat"
    t.string   "lon"
    t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
    t.integer  "scouting_report_id"
  end
```

The log reports 422, but no errors:

> Started POST "/scouting_reports.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-03-25
>   13:41:55 -0600 Processing by ScoutingReportsController#create as JSON 
>   Parameters: {"scouting_report"=>{"crop_water_use"=>"Yes. Water is
>   used.", "crop_water_use_units"=>"IPD", "wind_speed"=>"12",
>   "report_date"=>"2017-03-25T19:41:55Z",
>   "scouting_report_details_attributes"=>[{"identifiaction"=>"Looks like
>   it's there", "action"=>"Treat", "disorder"=>"", "lon"=>"-97.989378",
>   "level"=>"3", "lat"=>"40.875492", "disorder_id"=>158}],
>   "wind_speed_degree"=>"10", "sky"=>"B", "crop_growth_stage"=>"Stage 1",
>   "temperature"=>"68", "wind_speed_direction"=>"NW",
>   "irrigation_comment"=>"The crops are irrigated if not irritated",
>   "stand_count"=>"12", "crop_condition_comments"=>"Comment about the
>   conditions", "crop_id"=>"1234"}}    (0.1ms)  BEGIN    (0.1ms) 
>   ROLLBACK Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 33ms (Views: 0.2ms |
>   ActiveRecord: 4.4ms)

**Raw JSON Payload**

```
{
    "scouting_report" : {
        "crop_water_use" : "Yes. Water is used.",
        "crop_water_use_units" : "IPD",
        "wind_speed" : "12",
        "report_date" : "2017-03-25T14:45:10Z",
        "scouting_report_details_attributes" : [
            {
                "identifiaction" : "Looks like it's there",
                "action" : "Treat",
                "disorder" : "",
                "lon" : "-97.989378",
                "level" : "3",
                "lat" : "40.875492",
                "disorder_id" : 158
            }
        ],
        "wind_speed_degree" : "10",
        "sky" : "B",
        "crop_growth_stage" : "Stage 1",
        "temperature" : "68",
        "wind_speed_direction" : "NW",
        "irrigation_comment" : "The crops are irrigated if not irritated",
        "stand_count" : "12",
        "crop_condition_comments" : "Comment about the conditions",
        "crop_id" : "1234"
    }
}
```

Just need another set of eyes. I'm sure I'm just missing something simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `inverse_of` in your associations:

```
class ScoutingReport < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :scouting_report_details, inverse_of: :scouting_report
end

class ScoutingReportDetail < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :scouting_report, inverse_of: :scouting_report_details
end
```

Comment: I thought rails was able to infer that if it wasn't explicit. Did that change in rails 5? Thanks, btw! It works!

Comment: No, you need to specify it explicit.